# Why my page load items, blink and then everything disappears?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have this code to read from an API and display all the information on the screen. When I try to access localhost:3000 I can see all the information, but it disappear right after.

Not sure if there is something missing, but I'm getting some warning on the console saying this:

index.js:1 Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain a  in .

Because it's just a warning I'm not sure if it would cause the error I'm getting, but I don't have any other error on the console...

I opened the source code and all the information is there and everything seems to be right.

Here's my index.js code:

```
const Index = (props) => (
    <Layout>
        <RecipeCardsLayout recipes={props.recipes} />
    </Layout>   
)

Index.getInitialProps = async function() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/public/recipes')
  const data = await res.json()

  console.log(`Show data fetched. Count: ${data.length}`)

  return {
    recipes: data
  }
}
```

Here my Layout code:

```
const Layout = props => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    {props.children} {/* important so Layout children will be rended */}
  </div>
)
```

Here's my header:

```
const Header = () => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>How to Keto Cook</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    </Head>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">How to Keto Cook</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
)
```

And here's where I believe there is something missing:
It's the RecipeCardsLayout

```
class RecipeCardsLayout extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        let rows = [];

        while(this.props.recipes.length > 0){
            var recipes = this.props.recipes.splice(0, 4);
            let cols = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++){
                let col = [];                
                col.push(
                    <div class='col-sm-3'>
                        <RecipeCard id={recipes[i].id} name={recipes[i].name} url={recipes[i].image.url}></RecipeCard>
                    </div>
                );

                cols.push(col);
            }
            let row = <div class='row'>{cols}</div>;
            rows.push(row);
        }

        return (
            <div>{rows}</div>               
        )
   }

}
```

If someone could give me a direction about how to debug and find this error would be awesome. I'm new to React and Nextjs and finding it a little bit difficult to debug this one as I can't see any error on consoles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead...

```
class RecipeCardsLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          recipes.map(recipe => {
            return (
              <div className="row" key={recipe.id}>
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                  <RecipeCard id={recipe.id} name={recipe.name} url={recipe.image.url} />
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the `render()` method, what is happening is that we're looping through the `recipes` array by calling the `map` method and returning a node that contains a row element, column element and the recipe card for each recipe.

Note that we're also using `className` instead of `class` on the `<div>`'s.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this is actually similar to what I had before. I am trying to display 4 cards per row and that is why I changed it. They way you suggested, only shows 1 per line.

Comment: @PalomaSchkrab Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is simple add a Fragment on your `{props.children}`

```
const Layout = props => (
  <div>
    <Header />
    <>{props.children}</> {/* important so Layout children will be rended */}
  </div>
)
```